# Django admin page layout changed with new version

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am working on an existing django project where admin console is extensively used.
With my latest run of package upgrade for my application admin page layout has changed.

Models have started appearing on all the pages, leaving a small space to display form fields.
For example this is how form page look like now:
[image]

Original Form view was occupying the whole page like this:
[image]

Any clue on what has been changed and which setting to change to get back the original view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1) [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/),

> The admin now has a sidebar on larger screens for easier navigation.
> It is enabled by default but can be disabled by using a custom
> **AdminSite** and setting [**`AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.enable_nav_sidebar)
> to False.

You can refer [Customizing the AdminSite class - (django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-adminsite) to know more about *customizing the `AdminSite`*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, open your browser and clear all the history then login back in again and it should work. I am sure the browser has cached an old version of Django admin.

I had the same problem when using version 3.1. I started a new demo app with version 2.2 to demonstrate something and when I got back to version 3.1 I got that issue, So what I did was just clear the browser history and everything came to its original state.